# Where are the root CAs stored on OS X?

Tags: macos, security, keychain, certificate

I need one of the root CA certificates, as a filename, to pass to a command-line program.  I could download it from DigiCert (and convert it to the required format, .crt) manually, but I figure it's easier to just use the CA that OS X must already have.  It's a common certificate, and all my Linux servers already have it, for example.

In the "Keychain Access" app, the correct certificate does exist, but I can't find anything that says where it lives.

Do these CAs exist in the filesystem, or only in an opaque proprietary format for OS X APIs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root CAs are stored in:

/System/Library/Keychains/SystemCACertificates.keychain
/System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain

Yes, these are OS X keychain files which are opaque, though not necessarily proprietary. You could theoretically use OS X's Keychain Services APIs to get at the certificate data inside the keychain file, but that might be overkill.

If you want a tangible copy of any of the root CA certificates, just select it in Keychain Access, and drag them to the Desktop to make a copy of them in .cer format.

(You can also use Quick Look in the Finder to preview the certificate info).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the security tool on OSX to list search for specific certificates in one or more Keychains.

From Big Sur the default locations used for the System Keychains are

- /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain
- /Library/Keychains/System.keychain

and for your personal login keychain

- /Users//Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db

The security command line program (see man security) can be used to list, export and search for certificates stored in these keychains.

Exporting all root certificates to a PEM encoded bundle:

```
security export -t certs -f pemseq -k /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain -o /tmp/all_certs.pem
```

If you want a specific certificate where you know the Common Name in the keychain "KEYCHAIN" instead try:

```
security find-certificate -p -c "COMMON NAME" "KEYCHAIN"
```

If you pipe it through openssl you can then easily verify it is the right certificate as so:

```
security find-certificate -p -c "COMMON NAME" "KEYCHAIN" | openssl x509 -text -noout
```

**For example;** To find all Root Certs with the string "Apple" in its name and display them in PEM format you would use

```
security find-certificate -p -c "Apple" /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain
```

There are many, many more options for the "security" program to work with keychains so you need to read the man page. It's a quite useful program that doesn't seem to be well known.